# KVM + virsh: the storage pool is empty

Tags: kvm, virsh

I am new to KVM and virsh command

I want to change my storage-pool to some other folder

but before that i dont see any default storage pool

```
$ virsh pool-list --all                

 Name   State   Autostart
---------------------------
```

the following happens when i try to dump xml (which i am trying to change default storage location)

```
$ virsh pool-dumpxml default > pool.xml
error: failed to get pool 'default'
error: Storage pool not found: no storage pool with matching name 'default'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can create a new default storage pool:

1. create a new directory for the storage pool - here "homelab" will be used as an example.

   `$ mkdir -p /kvm/pools/homelab`
2. define the pool

   `$ virsh pool-define-as --name default --type dir --target /kvm/pools/homelab`

   `Pool default defined`
3. set the pool to start at the same time as libvirtd

   `$ virsh pool-autostart default`
4. start the pool

   `virsh pool-start default`

Here you can create a pool with another name instead of default.
To change the storage path of a existing pool, use the command:

`$ virsh pool-edit default`

Finally, observe the pool using `virsh pool-list`